# How to change default branch when using arc diff?

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

The first time I used arc diff to submit a branch, it asked me which branch to compare changes to. I entered `origin/master`. This compares it to all the changes that have been made to the Master branch. Now it always uses the Master to compare it to which I want to change to `origin/develop`.

I was wondering if there was a way to change the default branch somehow so instead of using `arc diff origin/develop` I can just use `arc diff`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Not sure why this is downvoted, but there are numerous occasions where we intend to create revisions diffed against a different branch.

When you selected `origin/master`, `arc` writes this info to a file `.git/arc/default-relative-commit`.

Edit this file to contain a different relative commit branch to contain,

`origin/develop`

Your next revisions will get created against the `origin/develop` branch when you issue `arc diff`.

You can change it back to `origin/master` when you need to create revisions off `master` again.

Hope this helps.